# What is the correct way to convert ODataQueryOptions<T> to IQueryable<T> when using expand?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have a project written using C# on the top of ASP.NET Core/5 framework. I am trying to use OData to allow users to query my WebAPI. Here is one endpoints where I want to allow the user to get the first matching records

```
public C2BaseController<TModel> : BaseController
{
    protected DbSet<TModel> EntityDbSet { get; private set;}

    public C2BaseController(DbContext context)
    {
        EntityDbSet = context.Set<TModel>;
    }
    
    public async Task<ActionResult<TModel>> SingleAsync()
    {
        var settings = new ODataValidationSettings()
        {
            AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions,
            AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All,
        };

        ODataQueryOptions<TModel> queryOptions = Request.GetODataQueryOptions<TModel>();

        queryOptions.Validate(settings);

        // This works great if Expand() is not used
        var query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(EntityDbSet) as IQueryable<TModel>;

        TModel model = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return model;
    }
}
```

The above code works as it should for the most part. However when the user request to expand property, the line `queryOptions.ApplyTo(EntityDbSet) as IQueryable<TModel>` returns null.

When the user request to expand a relation, the `queryOptions.ApplyTo(EntityDbSet)` cannot be casted to `IQueryable<TModel>`.

How can I correctly cast `ODataQueryOptions<T>` to `IQueryable<T>` when using expand so I can query the database?

Comment: Does this article useful to you ? [Converting ODataQueryOptions into LINQ Expressions in C#](https://d-fens.ch/2017/03/01/converting-odataqueryoptions-into-linq-expressions-in-c/)